# Making a query in SQL using the avg function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
EMPLOYEE(ID_Employee, Employee_name,Job,#ID_Dep)
DEPARTMENT (ID_Dep, Dep_name)
HOLIDAY (#ID_Employee, #Date_B, Days)
```

**TO DO:** a query to list the ID and name of all the employee's who have had holidays longer (in days) than the average of their cooworkers in the same department and with the same job.

**Example:**

```
IF we have

Sara: ID: 1, Department 12, working as secretary. Has spent 12 days in vacation
Jenna: ID: 9, Department 12, working as secretary. Has spent 10 days in vacation
Anna: ID: 3, Department 10, working as HR. Has spent 15 days in vacation
Jenna: ID: 5, Department 10, working as HR. Has spent 12 days in vacation
John: ID: 10, Department 1, working as consulant. Has spent 10 days in vacation
```

**In this case the query would list Sara, Anna and John and their respective ID’s.**

**Which would be the correct way to implement this ?**

**What have I tried ?**

I can list the employees that have had holidays longer than the average of their cooworkers from all the departments.I don't know how to do it for each department.

**My Code**

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.ID_Client, EMPLOYEE.Client_name
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE (SELECT HOLIDAY.Days FROM HOLIDAY > SELECT AVG(HOLIDAY.Days));
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I can list the employees that have had holidays longer than the average of their cooworkers from all the departments.I don't know how to do it for each department.

Comment: What is the relationship between HOLIDAY and EMPLOYEE?

Comment: @vidaica its a non-hierarchical union that contains data.It contains the outside key from employee and another table as a primary one.

Comment: Can you write a query to calculate the average holidays per department?

Comment: @vidaica I think I wrote a query where I get only the employees which have longer than average holiday durations,but I don't know how to do it for each department.The code is above btw.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select e.*, h.*. t.*
from EMPLOYEE as e
left join HOLIDAY h
on e.ID_Employee = h.ID_Employee
left join (
Select sum(h.Days)/count(distinct e.ID_Employee) as average, d.ID_Dep as dept_id
from EMPLOYEE as e
left join HOLIDAY h
on e.ID_Employee = h.ID_Employee
left join DEPARTMENT d
 on  d.ID_Dep = e.ID_Dep
group by dept
) as t on e.ID_Dep = t.dept_id
where h.Days > t.average
```

Here, create a derived table(dept) which has the average number of holidays taken by employees in each department. Now joining the derived table with employees and return the users who have taken more than average number of holiday(joining with derived table on dept id)

May be you need some tweaking.

Comment: all those left joins bro... Could you please explain your code a bit more.I understand it partially.My teacher hasn't really explained anything ...

Comment: Hmm.. Your teacher's lecture is not the entire Encyclopedia. Google and read before seeking help

Comment: Hmm if that's what you think,your code isn't the best bro.You clearly use sum and count when you could use avg.And you clearly did not read my post where I explained that I needed only the name and id of the person who has more holidays than the average one. -1 noone forced you to write something.

Comment: @Lind: Are you seeking to find the employees who had *contiguous* vacations longer than corresponding average ones or the employees that had *total* days spent in vacation more than the average? Depending on the answer to that, `sum() / count(distinct)` might actually make more sense than `avg()`.

Comment: @cjg: To understand what an outer join is is one thing, to understand why it has been used in a particular way for a particular problem is quite another. In short, it would indeed be better if you explained how your solution works. What if you made a mistake in your code? Trying to describe your method to others might actually help you to see it (or to make sure that there's no one).

Comment: @Andriy, "My teacher hasn't really explained anything". I could not digest that one. "A bad workman blames his tools. I totally agree with you, I should have explained my approach to solution in answer itself.

Comment: @AndriyM I am trying to find the employees who had contigous vacations longer than corresponding average ones. "cjg" I am studying for computer engineering and unfortunately I have 6 subjects which I study during my semester.Having a bad teacher really hurts me alot because I don't have the free time someone might have to learn it all by himself.I asked very politely for you to explain the code,you replied in a rude way...

Comment: @Lind, I too had studied Computer Engg, but with 8 papers per semester. Even after 5 years as Engineer, I regularly read Textbooks/Articles. Its not just me, more than 90% people in here are so. You circular is just to help you to understand concepts and to teach you how to learn.